# Retrieve function argument types with Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to type a `useStateUpdater` React Hook, that will take an initial state, and a curried function that will provide, first, the current state, and second, an optional argument.

Valid usages are:

```
const [state, toggle] = useStateUpdater(false, bool => () => !bool);
toggle();
console.log(state); // true
```

or

```
const [str, append] = useStateUpdater('foo', str => more => str + more);
append('bar');
console.log(str); // 'foobar'
```

This is my hook code, with the types I was able to define so far:

```
// @flow
import { useState } from 'react';

type UseStateUpdater = <S, U>(
  initialState: (() => S) | S,
  updater: U
) => [S, any => void];

const useStateUpdater: UseStateUpdater = ((initialState, updater) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  return [state, (...args) => setState(state => updater(state)(...args))];
}: any);

export default useStateUpdater;
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is that at the moment, the returned `updater` function has `any` as arguments type.

I would like it to have as arguments type the types of the `U` type, on the second function.

```
useStateUpdater(S, S => ARGS => S);
                        ^
                        How do I reference this?
```

As pseudo code, the type should look like:

```
type UseStateUpdater = <S, U>(
  initialState: (() => S) | S,
  updater: U
) => [S, (...args: $Arguments<$ReturnType<typeof U>>) => void];
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to type it:

```
// @flow
import { useState } from 'react';

type UseStateUpdater = <S, U>(
  initialState: (() => S) | S,
  updater: S => U => S
) => [S, U => void];

const useStateUpdater: UseStateUpdater = ((initialState, updater) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  return [state, (...args) => setState(state => updater(state)(...args))];
}: any);

export default useStateUpdater;
```